# Tooltip Image set fixed position

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-hover, jquery-tooltip

I have searched this topic and although I have found similar situations I was unable to apply it to my specific needs. I have a plugin for a wordpress site which enables me to display an image as a tooltip on a link hover. It works perfectly, the only problem I am having is that I want every image tooltip to have a fixed position on the page which doesn't change regardless of the location of the mouse/link on the hover. Right now the tooltip follows the mouse on whichever link I choose. For reference, I am trying it function like the hover images on this site: http://www.themorrisongallery.com/artists.html where there is a stationary fixed location which shows the image on the mouseover.

This is the plugin that I am using: http://smartcatdesign.net/wp-tooltip-with-images-free-wordpress-plugin/

Here is what the CSS currently looks like:

```
.sc-tooltip-wrapper{
width: auto;
height: auto;
float: right;
margin: 0px;
background: #ffffff;
color: #333333;
z-index: 9999;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -50px;



.sc-tooltip-wrapper img{
float: right;
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: relative;
```

and here is what the script looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var ctr = 0;
$('.sc-tooltip').each(function() {

    ctr++;
    var tooltips = '<div id="sc-tooltip' + ctr + '-box" class="sc-tooltip-wrapper"><img src="' + $(this).attr('data-image') + '"/></div>';
    $('body').append(tooltips);
    $(this).attr('id', 'sc-tooltip' + ctr);
});
$('.sc-tooltip').hover(function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var theId = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-box';
    var leftOfset = $(theId).width();
    $(theId).css({'left': x, 'top': y});
    $(theId).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
    var theId = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-box';
    $(theId).fadeOut(100);
});
```

any suggestions would be very appreciated! I have been trying to set a fixed position using css and using the 'top' and 'left' attributes but everytime I do that the image just disappears from the page completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually looking to get the image `position: fixed`, then it wouldn't scroll with the page...

Try this CSS:

```
.sc-tooltip-wrapper{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px; /* Set the position you want here */
    left: 100px; /* Set the position you want here */
}

.sc-tooltip-wrapper img{
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

And this javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var ctr = 0;
$('.sc-tooltip').each(function() {

    ctr++;
    var tooltips = '<div id="sc-tooltip' + ctr + '-box" class="sc-tooltip-wrapper"><img src="' + $(this).attr('data-image') + '"/></div>';
    $('body').append(tooltips);
    $(this).attr('id', 'sc-tooltip' + ctr);
});
$('.sc-tooltip').hover(function(e) {
    //var x = e.pageX;
    //var y = e.pageY;
    //var theId = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-box';
    //var leftOfset = $(theId).width();
    //$(theId).css({'left': x, 'top': y});
    //$(theId).fadeIn(200); // Nice effect...
    $(theId).show(); // But this makes it more like your example
}, function() {
    var theId = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-box';
    //$(theId).fadeOut(100); // Nice effect...
    $(theId).hide(); // But this makes it more like your example
});
```

What I've done is quite simply stopping the javascript from updating the images position as you hover the link. It stays in the position set in the CSS.

Also, changed `$(theId).fadeIn(100);`to `$(theId).show();`and `$(theId).fadeOut(100);`to `$(theId).hide();`to make the behavior more like that in the example you linked. I would guess the original is a bit smoother/softer and nicer, just wanted to give you the choice!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I modified both the CSS and the javascript just as you provided, however I am not seeing the image at all when I hover over the links. I've been playing around with various values for the css `top: 500px` and `left: 500px` and with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard without seeing the actual page. Is it online so you can link?

Comment: Thanks for the link, helped a lot! Seems like you have forgotten to comment out the row `$(theId).css({'left': x, 'top': y});` as in my answer, giving an error.

Comment: Also, I noticed another error in the console, you have forgotten to close the script tag around your Google Analytics tracking code: `<p><script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');</script></p>`.

Comment: Thank you so much it is working now and it works perfectly! I seriously appreciate you helping me out!! : )